# ListViewを最下部まで来たら20件ずつにタイムラインを取得する方法は？

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter4j

いつも有難うございます。
Twitterの自作アプリを改良しています。
NOW LOADINGのところは無事完成したのですが、ListViewの最下部まで来たら自動的に次のタイムライン20件ずつの取得するようを試みているのですが、取得できていない状態が続き、
なかなかうまくいきません。
API制限の回避するために実装します。
どのように組み込んだらタイムラインを20件ずつ取得することができますでしょうか？
ご教示願います。

### 該当のソースコード

```
        ListView lv = getListView();
     // ListViewが最下層に来たら動的にタイムラインを20件取得
            lv.addFooterView(getFooter());
            lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                // スクロールした時の処理
                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
                    AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {

                        @Override
                        protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);


                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                //
                                e.printStackTrace();


                            }
                            return null;

                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {

                            if (result != null) {

                                // 最下部までスクロールしたら
                                if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) == firstVisibleItem) {

                                    // くるくる回ってるのを1個削除
                                    Integer ItemCount = totalItemCount - 1;


                                    // ツイート追加
                                    for (int i = ItemCount; i < (ItemCount + COUNT_MAX); i++) {
                                        mAdapter.add(result.get(i));
                                    }
                                    //getListView().invalidateViews();




                                }

                            }
                        }
                    };
                    task.execute();


                }


            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
            }
            });
```

### 全体のソースコード

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {

    private TweetAdapter mAdapter;
    private Twitter mTwitter;
    private long rt_id=0;
    private static final int RATE_LIMITED_STATUS_CODE = 400;
    private static final int COUNT_MAX =30;
    private static ProgressDialog waitDialog;
    private View mFooter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (!TwitterUtils.hasAccessToken(this)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TwitterOAuthActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {

            mTwitter = TwitterUtils.getTwitterInstance(this);
            mAdapter = new TweetAdapter(this);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);

            ListView lv = getListView();
         // ListViewが最下層に来たら動的にタイムラインを20件取得
                lv.addFooterView(getFooter());
                lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

                    // スクロールした時の処理
                    @Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, final int firstVisibleItem, final int visibleItemCount, final int totalItemCount) {
                        AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {

                            @Override
                            protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(500);


                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    //
                                    e.printStackTrace();


                                }
                                return null;

                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {

                                if (result != null) {

                                    // 最下部までスクロールしたら
                                    if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) == firstVisibleItem) {

                                        // くるくる回ってるのを1個削除
                                        Integer ItemCount = totalItemCount - 1;


                                        // ツイート追加
                                        for (int i = ItemCount; i < (ItemCount + COUNT_MAX); i++) {
                                            mAdapter.add(result.get(i));
                                        }
                                        //getListView().invalidateViews();




                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        };
                        task.execute();


                    }


                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView arg0, int arg1) {
                }
                });



            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                        final int position, final long id) {
                    //Tweetクリックメニュー
                    final Status item = (Status) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    //username
                    final String user ="@"+ item.getUser().getScreenName() ;
                    //公式RT
                    rt_id =item.getId();

                    //showToast(String.valueOf(rt_id));
                    //popup-menu
                    final CharSequence[] items = {"返信","全員へ返信", "公式RT","このtweetをお気に入り登録する"};

                    final AlertDialog.Builder listDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                    listDlg.setTitle(user+"さんへどうする？");
                    listDlg.setNegativeButton("閉じる",null);
                    listDlg.setItems(
                        items,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
                                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_tweet, null);
                                Button btn =(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.action_tweet);

                                final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_text);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                //switch-case
                                switch(which){
                                case 0:
                                    //showToast((String) items[0]);

                                    editText.setText(user +" ");

                                    editText.setSelection(user.length()+1);



                                    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                            if(dialog != null){
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }

                                            AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
                                                @Override
                                                protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                                                    try {
                                                        // �ԐM
                                                        mTwitter.updateStatus(params[0]);

                                                        return true;
                                                    } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                                        return false;
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                                     dialog.dismiss();
                                                    if (result) {
                                                       showToast("返信しました");
                                                       editText.setText("");
                                                    } else {

                                                        showToast("返信できませんでした");

                                                    }
                                                }
                                            };
                                            task.execute(editText.getText().toString());
                                        }


                                    });

                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                        .setTitle(user+"さんへ"+(String) items[0])
                                        .setView(view)
                                        .setPositiveButton( "閉じる", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            } }) .show();

                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    //�S���֕ԐM

                                    UserMentionEntity[] ume = item.getUserMentionEntities();
                                 if(ume != null){

                                    List<String> reply = new ArrayList<String>();
                                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                    for(int i=0;i<ume.length;i++){
                                        UserMentionEntity replyall=ume[i];
                                        reply.add("@"+replyall.getScreenName());
                                        sb.append("@"+replyall.getScreenName()+" ");

                                    }


                                    String[] replies = ( String[] )reply.toArray( new String[0] );
                                    String userall=user+" "+ new String(sb);
                                    editText.setText(user+" "+ new String(sb));
                                    editText.setSelection(userall.length());
                                    //showToast(String.valueOf(userall.length())+"����");

                                 }

                              btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        if(dialog != null){
                                            dialog.dismiss();
                                        }



                                        AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> task = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>() {
                                            @Override
                                            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

                                                try {
                                                    // �ԐM
                                                    mTwitter.updateStatus(params[0]);


                                                    return true;
                                                } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                                    return false;
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                                 dialog.dismiss();
                                                if (result) {
                                                   showToast("全員へ返信しました");
                                                   editText.setText("");
                                                } else {

                                                    showToast("返信できませんでした。");

                                                }
                                            }
                                        };
                                        task.execute(editText.getText().toString());
                                    }


                                });

                              final AlertDialog.Builder listDlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                              new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle((String) items[1])
                                .setView(view)
                                .setPositiveButton( "閉じる", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        dialog.dismiss();
                                    } }) .show();


                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    //RT
                                    AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean> rt = new AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean>(){
                                        @Override
                                        protected Boolean doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                            try{
                                                mTwitter.retweetStatus(params[0]).getId();

                                                return true;
                                            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                return false;
                                            }
                                        }
                                         @Override
                                            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                                 dialog.dismiss();
                                                if (result) {
                                                   showToast("公式RTしました");
                                                } else {
                                                    showToast("公式RTできませんでした");
                                                }
                                            }
                                };
                                    rt.execute(rt_id);

                                    break;

                                case 3:
                                    //  ���C�ɓ���
                                    AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean> fav = new AsyncTask<Long,Void,Boolean>(){

                                        @Override
                                        protected Boolean doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                            try {
                                                mTwitter.createFavorite((params[0])).getId();
                                                return true;
                                            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                                                // TODO �����������ꂽ catch �u���b�N
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                                return false;
                                            }


                                        }
                                         @Override
                                            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                                                 dialog.dismiss();
                                                if (result) {
                                                   showToast("tweetをお気に入り登録できませんでした");


                                                } else {

                                                    showToast("何らかの事情でtweetをお気に入り登録できませんでした。");

                                                }
                                            }


                                };
                                fav.execute(item.getId());
                                break;
                                }


                            }


                        });

                    // �\��

                    listDlg.create().show();
                }

            });



           reloadTimeLine();

            }

    }




    private View getFooter() {
        if (mFooter == null) {
            mFooter = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_footer,
                    null);
        }
        return mFooter;
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_refresh:
            reloadTimeLine();
            showToast("更新しました");
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_tweet:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, TweetActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_reply:
            showToast("リプライ一覧を取得しています。");
            replyTimeLine();
            showToast("リプライ一覧を取得しました。");
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    //Twitter
    private class TweetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<twitter4j.Status> {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public TweetAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tweet, null);
            }

            Status item = getItem(position);
            //UserName
            TextView name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            name.setText(item.getUser().getName());
            //@xxx(userID)
            TextView screenName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.screen_name);
            screenName.setText("@" + item.getUser().getScreenName());
            //本文
           TextView text=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);


            //TWのキャラの仕掛け

            String str = item.getText();


            /*if(str.indexOf("@")!=-1){
                String x_user ="@"+item.getInReplyToScreenName();
                UserMentionEntity[] ume = item.getUserMentionEntities();
                 if(ume != null){
                    List reply = new ArrayList();
                    for(int i=0;i<ume.length;i++){
                        UserMentionEntity replyall=ume[i];

                        reply.add(x_user);
                        if(str.indexOf(x_user)!= -1){
                            int start = str.indexOf(x_user);
                            int end = x_user.length();
                            SpannableString spannable = new SpannableString(str);
                            BackgroundColorSpan span = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.argb(50, 184, 101, 204));
                            spannable.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                            text.setText(spannable);
                        }else{
                            text.setText(item.getText());
                        }


                    }

                    String[] replies = ( String[] )reply.toArray( new String[0] );


                }


            }
            else{ */
                text.setText(str);
           //   }


            //UserIcon
            String iconUrl =item.getUser().getProfileImageURL();
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(iconUrl).into(icon);
           //RT
            ImageView rt_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rt_icon);
            if(item.isRetweet()){
                String rtUrl =item.getRetweetedStatus().getUser().getProfileImageURL();
                Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(rtUrl).into(rt_icon);
                rt_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
                rt_icon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            //Userタイムラインの画像の表示

            MediaEntity[] mediaEntitys = item.getExtendedMediaEntities();
            ImageView media1=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            ImageView media2=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            ImageView media3=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
            ImageView media4=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);



            if(mediaEntitys !=null){
                List list = new ArrayList();

                for( int i = 0; i < mediaEntitys.length; i ++ ){
                    MediaEntity mediaEntity = mediaEntitys[i];
                    String mediaURL = mediaEntity.getMediaURL()+":small";
                    list.add(mediaURL);
                }
                String[] medias = ( String[] )list.toArray( new String[0] );

                switch(mediaEntitys.length){
                case 1:
                    media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[1]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[1]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media2);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[2]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media3);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    media1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    media4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[0]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media1);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[1]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media2);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[2]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media3);
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(medias[3]).thumbnail(0.1f).into(media4);
                    break;
                default:
                    media1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    media2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    break;

                }


            }else{
                media1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                media4.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            return convertView;
        }
    }

    private void replyTimeLine(){
        AsyncTask<Void,Void,ResponseList<Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void,Void,ResponseList<Status>>(){

            @Override
            protected ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try{
                    Paging paging = new Paging();
                    paging.setCount(10);
                    return mTwitter.getMentionsTimeline(paging);
                }catch(TwitterException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                        mAdapter.add(status);
                    }
                    getListView().setSelection(0);

                } else {
                    showToast("リプライを取得できませんでした");

                }
            }
        };
        task.execute();

        }

    //timeline
    private void reloadTimeLine() {
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                //NOWLOADING画面表示
                Log.d("TAG_ASYNCTASK", "onPreExecute");
                // Dialog表示
                waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                waitDialog.setMessage("NOW LOADING...");
                waitDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                waitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                waitDialog.show();


            }

            @Override
            protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                int page = 1;
                ResponseList<twitter4j.Status> tl = null;
                int total = 0;


                while (true) {
                    Paging paging = new Paging(page++,COUNT_MAX);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                        if (tl == null) {
                            tl = mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
                        } else {

                            total = tl.size();
                            tl.addAll(mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging));
                        }

                        if (tl.size() == total) {
                            break;
                        }

                     } catch (TwitterException e) {
                        if (RATE_LIMITED_STATUS_CODE != e.getStatusCode()) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
                return tl;



            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {

                if (result != null) {
                    if (waitDialog.isShowing()){waitDialog.dismiss();}
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                        mAdapter.add(status);
                    }
                    getListView().setSelection(0);


                } else {
                    showToast("タイムラインの取得に失敗しました。。。");

                }
            }
        };
        task.execute();
    }

    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

以下が追加読み込み判定。

スクロールリスナを追加

```
lv.setOnScrollListener(mOnScrollListner);
```

スクロールリスナを作成

```
OnScrollListener mOnScrollListner = new OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (getListView().getLastVisiblePosition() == (mAdapter.getCount() - 1)){
            moreLoadTimeLine();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
            int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    }
};
```

以下が追加読み込み処理。

```
private void moreLoadTimeLine(){
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<twitter4j.Status>>() {
        @Override
        protected List<twitter4j.Status> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Paging paging = new Paging();
                twitter4j.Status status = mAdapter.getItem(mAdapter.getCount()-1);
                paging.setMaxId(status.getId());

                return mTwitter.getHomeTimeline(paging);
            } catch (TwitterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<twitter4j.Status> result) {
            if (result != null) {
                for (twitter4j.Status status : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(status);
                }
                getListView().invalidate();

            } else {
                showToast("タイムラインの取得に失敗しました。。。");

            }
        }
    };
    task.execute();
}
```

Comment: 重ね重ね有難うございます。┏○))ﾍﾟｺり
タイムラインの取得に大分時間がかかってから表示されたのですが最下層にスクロールしてもくるくるが出てるだけでそれ以降のタイムラインの取得ができていない状況です(TдT)

Answer (score 1):

最強クロエ様のヒントを元に下記の通りにソースコードを書き換え成功しました。
閲覧有難うございました。

```
 AbsListView.OnScrollListener mOnScrollListner = new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    boolean isloading = false;
    boolean isAllLoad = false;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) { }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(final AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {



        // (item総数 - 表示されているitem総数) =  表示されているitemのindex
        //  で最下部の検知
        if ((totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) == firstVisibleItem) {
            isloading = true;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(5000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                           moreLoadTimeLine();
                            // 全て読み込んだらプログレスバーを削除
                            if (MAX_ITEM <= mAdapter.getCount()) {
                               mFooter.setVisibility(view.GONE);
                                isAllLoad = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    isloading = false;
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

OnScrollが発生するたびにAsyncTaskが作られるので、タスクQueueが大変なことになりそうです。
最下部スクロール判定後にAsyncTaskを生成してはどうでしょう。

また、日本語だけの検索ではHit件数が少なくなりがちです。
英語でも検索してみるといいでしょう。

日本人は英語は嫌いになりがちですが、
エンジニアは英語できたほうが変数名/クラス名を解りやすく定義できるので、
積極的に英語を覚えていったほうがいいです。

例えば「android listview endless scroll」とか。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list

参考までに。

Comment: 有難うございます。
参考にやってみましたが、仕組みは分かったんですけどツイート部分の取得がどうしてもわからず積んでしまいましたOTL
相変わらずくるくる回りっぱなしの状態が続いてます(TдT)